# Writing a Content Part that contains a list of content parts

Tags: orchardcms

I've been trying to write a simple accordian widget, where each section of accordian would be its own content part. I have the leafs content part created fine, but I want to create the accordian part which contains a list of the leafs. I havn't been able to find a good tutorial that went over something like this. I'm working on displaying the leafs now, and am running into issues. I'm trying to mimic the comments module. This is what I have. It seems like i am able to get up to the list of leafs in the driver, but i'm not sure what to do with the view. i see comments calls @Display(Model.List) but i have no idea what this is doing.

Edit View (Just using a textbox for one leaf id, need to figure out how to select leaves):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Accordian Fields</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccordianLeaf)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccordianLeaf,
                                  new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(service.GetComments(), "Value", "Text"))*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccordianLeaf)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccordianLeaf)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Model:

```
namespace SuccessCenter.Models
{
    public class AccordianRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual int AccordianLeaf { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccordianPart : ContentPart<AccordianRecord>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title
        {
            get { return Retrieve(r => r.Title); }
            set { Store(r => r.Title, value); }
        }
        [Required]
        public int AccordianLeaf
        {
            get { return Retrieve(r => r.AccordianLeaf); }


       set { Store(r => r.AccordianLeaf, value); }
    }
}
```

}

Handler:

```
namespace SuccessCenter.Handlers
{
    public class AccordianHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        public AccordianHandler(IRepository<AccordianRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        }
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
namespace SuccessCenter.Drivers
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class AccordianDriver : ContentPartDriver<AccordianPart>
    {
        private readonly IAccordian _accordian;

        public AccordianDriver(IAccordian accordian)
        {
            _accordian = accordian;
        }
        protected override DriverResult Display(AccordianPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
            //return ContentShape("Parts_Accordian", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Accordian(Title: part.Title, AccordianLeaf: part.AccordianLeaf));
            return Combined(
               ContentShape("Parts_Accordian",
                   () =>
                   {
                       // create a hierarchy of shapes
                       var firstLevelShapes = new List<dynamic>();
                       var allShapes = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();
                       var AccordianLeafs = _accordian.AccordianLeafs.ToList();

                       foreach (var item in AccordianLeafs)
                       {
                           var shape = shapeHelper.AccordianLeaf(ContentPart: item, ContentItem: item.ContentItem);
                           allShapes.Add(item.Id, shape);
                       }

                       var list = shapeHelper.List(Items: allShapes);

                       return shapeHelper.Parts_Accordian(
                           List: list
                           );
                   }));
        }

        //GET
        protected override DriverResult Editor(AccordianPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
            return ContentShape("Parts_Accordian_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Accordian", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
        }

        //POST
        protected override DriverResult Editor(AccordianPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
            updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
            return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using SuccessCenter.Models;
}<div class="expand-view expanded">
    <header class="bg-brand-blue txt-white relative">
        <h3 class="txt-left">@Model.List.Title</h3>
        <span class="toggle v-align absolute">
            <span class="expanded">Colllapse <i class="icons icon-carat-up-wh"></i></span><span class="collapsed">Expand <i class="icons icon-carat-down-wh"></i></span>
        </span>
    </header>
<section class="default-padding">
    @Model.List.AccordianLeaf
</section>
```

@*@Display(Model.List)*@

Answer (score 1):

The List shape (`shapeHelper.List()`) takes a range of content item shapes, which you seem to build with `shapeHelper.AccordionLeaf()`. Therefore you can just display it with the Display method:

```
@Display(Model.List)
```

This method will display the `List` property on your model (your model properties are the ones you give as parameter in `shapeHelper.Parts_Accordian(/* model properties */)`

I am not sure what you are trying to do in the view, it seems like your want to iterate over the items in the List shape? In that case you can do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.List.Items) {
    // item here is an AccordionLeaf shape
    @Display(item)
}
```